# How does a Lie algebra act on a tensor product of L-modules?

Tags: modules, lie-algebras, tensor-products

What is the $L$-module structure on $V\otimes W$ where $L$ is a Lie-algebra and $V,W$ are $L$-modules?

The following question is related but I can't find the definition in there:
[tensor product of modules of Lie algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57681/tensor-product-of-modules-of-lie-algebras)

Comment: look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra_representation

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what i needed: $x(v\otimes w)=(xv)\otimes w+v\otimes(xw)$

Comment: Glad to help, I think usually the answer to such questions is something along the lines of: it's the only formula which makes sense given the circumstances.

Comment: @James: that seems totally unhelpful. For example, you might have guessed that it was $x(v \otimes w) = (xv) \otimes (xw)$, like it is for groups. There's something to explain here.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan fair enough (in this case), but, I think it is not unreasonable to suggest that in many such situations it is enough to write what can be written.